# How can rename a folder which is in another path?

Tags: python, python-3.x, rename, file-rename

I need to rename folders in my code.

My current code:

```
target_file = input("Input folder that you want to rename >>>")
rename = input("Please write a new name for it >>> ")
try :
  os.rename(target_file, rename)
  print("Successfull")
except :
  print("!!! You didn't write file name right. Try again !!!")
```

This code renaming folders in current working path. But I need to rename files in other paths, like this:

```
os.rename(C:\\user\\oldname, newname)
```

Is it possible?

Comment: Do you mean `os.rename('C:\\user\\oldname', 'c:\\user\\newname')` ?

Comment: `os.rename('C:/user/'+oldname, newname)`?

Comment: They did not work

Answer (score 0):

You can, but you have to be careful that you use the *absolute* path for the first argument, whereas the second is the *relative* path.

In two words, it means that you will find the file you are looking for, but that it will be saved *in the folder your script is running in.*

As the comment suggest, if you want to only rename while keeping it in the same place, you would have to write the absolute path every time or find a clever way to transpose the relative path you enter as a second argument into a relative path...

One idea would be to split your first argument in a way to get the absolute path minus the folder you want to rename :

`target_file_path = '/'.join(target_file.split('/')[:-1])`